# Xamarin validate invisible controls

Tags: c#, validation, xamarin, behavior, fluentvalidation

Basis of my questions is a simple form. Let's say we have 4 fields

- Surname
- Name
- Question: Do you have a cat?
- What's your cat's name
- a submit button

`Surname` and `question` and `cat's name` are required fields. If `Yes` is the answer, the field `cat's name` is becoming visible.

So far so good. I am using FluentValidation to validate these fields. In my validator, I create the rule for these 3 properties of my viewmodel.

Now I'd only like to validate `cat's name`, if it's visible. There is no way to remove rules. I also tried with behaviors, but at the time I click `submit` (which executes the save method in my viewmodel), I don't have access to my behaviors..

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: triggers can solve you problem
Refer https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/triggers/ for trigger implementation

Comment: @JayPatel I don't like disabled buttons, the user should be able to interact freely and be notified after trying to hit save.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your main question (how to conditionally run a rule/rules using FluentValidation), you have a couple of options. In general, I'd recommend this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.FluentValidationRules) (full disclosure, I wrote it), which helps keep things clean and also makes option 1 below a breeze.

#### Option 1: Run only relevant rules

Based on the value the user provided for has cat or not that you're binding to from your view, you could conditionally pull out the rules from the validator that exclude the rule(s) for that field:

**In ViewModel:**

```
        var context = new ValidationContext<YourClass>(catInfoStuff);

    if (doesNotHasCatLoL)
    {
        var descriptor = yourAbstractValidatorInstance.CreateDescriptor();
        var scopedRules = new List<IValidationRule>();

        foreach (var propName in listOfThePropertyNameStringsInYourClass)
            scopedRules.AddRange(descriptor.GetRulesForMember(propName));

        var fluentValidationResult = new ValidationResult(
            scopedRules.SelectMany(x => x.Validate(context)).ToList());
    }
    else
    {
        var fluentValidationResult = yourAbstractValidatorInstance.Validate(context);
    }
```

#### Option 2: Add a true/false flag to [RootContextData](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#root-context-data) for running the rule or not. e.g.:

**In ViewModel:**

```
        var context = new ValidationContext<YourClass>(catInfoStuff);
        context.RootContextData["HasCat"] = hasCatBindingValue; // from your view
```

**In AbstractValidator:**

```
        RuleFor(catname => catname.CatName)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
            .Custom((catname, context) =>
            {
                if (!context.ParentContext.RootContextData.ContainsKey("HasCat"))
                {
                    // You may not want to flag this, as you'd likely have a separate rule for that on the other property
                    context.AddFailure("You need to indicate whether you have a cat or not...");
                }
                else
                {
                    var hasCat = (bool)context.ParentContext.RootContextData["HasCat"];

                    if (hasCat && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(catname))
                    {
                        context.AddFailure("Please provide the name of your cat.");
                    }

                    // other checks, or just chain more below like you usually would since we StopOnFirstFailure
                }
            });
```